# How do you increment by more than 1 in map?

Tags: javascript

I have an array I want to increment over every other element. The 2nd element is always a repeat and I only want to process the first element. How can I get the map() method to increment by two and skip over one element?

```
let newArr = oldArr.map((item, i) => {
  // process oldArr[0] item
  // skips over oldArr[1] item
  //...
});
```

Comment: You could check for `i` to be even, or use a standard loop. `map` isn't necessarily the right tool here if you don't want to process every element.

Comment: If you `return false` from within the `map` callback it will skip that item. Combine that with what Carcigenicate said above and you've got a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.filter` to skip every second value:

```js
let oldArr = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5];

let newArr = oldArr.filter((v,i) => i % 2).map((item, i) => {
  console.log(item);
});
```

Comment: Use the implicit return of arrow functions: `oldArr.filter((v,i) => i % 2)`, BTW, he is trying to skip the items whose `i % 2` is `1` so change to `oldArr.filter((v,i) => i % 2 === 0)`